# Converting a list of nested strings into a nested list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I was wondering how to convert a list of nested strings into a nested list of strings using string manipulation like .split(), .strip(), and .replace(). A sample would be converting a sequence like (notice the single quote with double quotes):

```
['"Chipotle"', '"Pho"']
```

into something like:

```
[["Chipotle"], ["Pho"]]
```

Comment: `[[word.strip('"')] for word in inputlist]` would do that. This is rather a broad question if you are talking about doing this *in general*.

Comment: Do you ever have more than one inner string within the outer strings?, e.g. `"'foo','bar'"`? If so, you probably want `ast.literal_eval`, as that will convert multiple comma separated strings into a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

If your nested strings are in the form of '"A","B","C"', you can use the following:

```
s.split('"')[1::2]  split by double quote, only odd indices (i.e. between quotes)
```

If you want a nested list, you can use this expression inside a list comprehension, like this:

```
[s.split('"')[1::2] for s in thelist]
```

where `thelist` is the original list.

Why only odd indices? It comes from the structure of the string:

0th element of split() result would be part of the string before 1st quote;
1st - between the 1st and 2nd quotes; 
2nd - between the 2nd and 3rd, and so on.

We need only the strings between odd (opening) and even (closing) quotes.

Example:

```
t = ['"1","2","3","4"', '"5","6","7',"8"']
a = [s.split('"')[1::2] for s in t]
print(a)
```

prints

```
[['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8']]
```

Comment: What is `s`? Please elaborate and explain better and fully (the answer seems to have been abandoned half-way through). Input/ouput/etc.

Comment: `s` is a string (in the form described above, i.e. element of a list).

Comment: @Pynchia Thank you! The answer is now more fully explained